# PhpStorm create Live Templates with variables inside variable

Tags: templates, phpstorm, sublimetext3, code-snippets, live

I have a Snippet in Sublime Text that I'd like to migrate to PhpStorm

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[date('${3:Y-m-d H:i:s}'${1:, strtotime('${4:+1 Day}'${2:, strtotime(${5:\$date})})})]]></content>
    <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
    <tabTrigger>mdate</tabTrigger>
    <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
    <scope>source.php</scope>
</snippet>
```

That's the result in Sublime Text:

[image: That's the result in Sublime Text]

This is what I have so far in my Live Template:

```
date('$FORMAT$', strtotime('$DATE_MATH$', strtotime($DATE$)));
```

Edit:
My Goal is to get results like

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($date));
date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("+1 Day", strtotime($date)));
```

All using the same template. So I type mdate, tab.. select the optional chunk of code. if I press tab again, I go to the variables values else I can delete the chunk of code. 
Please pay attention to the 6 stages of the snippet in the gif.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Looks good so far. You can provide default value for each variable after you click on `Edit variables` button -- there is a "Default value" column. NOTE: the text value should be surrounded by `"` (double quotes) there. If that's not what you are asking here then please clarify it (e.g. with screenshot/gif from a PhpStorm -- how it should look there)

Comment: I edited my post. Its hard for me to explain what Im trying to achieve. Sry for that.

Comment: As far as my experience goes, you will not be able to create such 6-stage template when some variable creates another variable/placeholder: all placeholders must be known when abbreviation gets expanded. You can create different templates though: just add extra letter/digit at the end of the abbreviation to differentiate between them.

Comment: You can file a Feature Request ticket at the Issue Tracker (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA) and maybe one days it will be implemented... but I would not hold my breath for a fast implementation. Obviously, please check for any existing tickets before posting new one (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA?q="live+template" and https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEABKL?q="live+template").

Comment: I personally do not  remember such request. The most close that I could find is this one (optional sections): https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-6446, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-7615 (notice that it's in the Backlog project)

Comment: P.S. If you decide to post a new ticket .. or find an existing one that matches your needs, please post back the link here: I'm interested in following (starring) those tickets as well.

Comment: Thanks to your help. When I saw the live template features I knew that wont be possible to make it like sublime text. I will try to build a plugin that understands the sublime syntax on snippets. Edit: do not worry, as soon as I find a solution for what I want I will post it here

Comment: @LazyOne Here is the link of the issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-53708